# Proving an angle within a triangle is congruent to another?

Tags: triangles, angle

It's been a while since I've done conventional geometry. How can I verify that angle $A$ is congruent to angle $C$?

[image]

I have no idea how to go about this without more info. Thanks.

Comment: I learned this in school as "angles with pairwise orthogonal legs". I thought it seemed like a real hassle to check, and mostly forgot about it, but looking at the answers, I see that looking for complementary angles is a much easier way to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The angles $A$ and $B$ are complementary. So are the angles $B$ and $C$. Therefore, the angles $A$ and $C$ are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $A$ and $B$ add up to $90$ (since $A+B+90=180$)

Hence,

$$
B=90-A
$$

But, there is a triangle with angles $B$, $C$ and $90$. Hence by the angle sum property,

$$
B+C+90=180
$$

or,

$$
90-A+C+90=180
$$

or,

$$
C-A+180=180
$$

or

$$
C-A=0
$$

finally!,

$$
C=A
$$

**QED**

Some links which you might find useful to get back into math shape,

Triangles - http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Triangle#Related_Formulae_and_Theorems

Similarity - http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Similarity

Congruence - http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Congruent

### Short Hack for a very quick answer

In such problems usually (with lots of practice), you should be quickly able to guess that the answer is either $C=A$ or $C=90-A$.

After you are able to get this sort of intuition, the problem is very very easy to solve (especially if it is a MCQ question where no solution is required)

**Re-draw the diagram by making the angle $A$ very small (almost zero), then check if angle $C$ is very small (almost zero) or big (almost 90)**

If $C$ is small then the answer is $C=A$

If $C$ is big and almost equal to $90$ then the answer is $C=90-A$

Try this method yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$A+B=90=B+C.$$
Can you figure out?